# What should a Spring Boot developer know?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot by doing projects with it. I want to ask you guys, what should a Spring Boot developer know? What things should I know or milestones to set for me to be job ready? Can you give me examples of hard tasks that you did? Would like to implement some of them in my projects for getting more experience in the Framework.

I am not new to programming but I am looking to move towards the web. I have knowledge of JAVA and SQL.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should know Java , it's easy to go from there :)

Comment: I agree, but would like to know if there are some specialised algorithms or techniques to learn that are widely used.

Comment: Not really . You can start from here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: If you already know Spring, it's pretty much the same, but easier.  But with no XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a pretty naive answer, that works for me. I have interviewed a lot of guys who were applied to Spring vacancies, and NEVER I've asked any Spring Boot related questions.
As Spring Boot is most about auto-configurations, best candidate should know how it works under-the-hood.
Best advice here, to my mind, would be to try to implement your pet projects WITHOUT using Spring Boot, with plain Spring, and then convert it to Spring Boot. This way you will know and understand exactly, what powers Spring Boot gives you. =)